# VIM -Change waiting time for combined key maps

Tags: vim

In VIM, When I map for example `<F9><F10>` to a command and `<F9>` to another command , it waits for 1-2 seconds when I press F9 to allow me press `<F10>` to access the command mapped to `<F9><F10>` and if I don't press `<F10>` it executes the command mapped to `<F9>`.

Is there a way to change this waiting time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`:help timeout` should give you all the information you need. Specifically, the `timeoutlen` setting does what you want.